# C# Interface to DLL and ExecutionEngineException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, dll

Newbie to C#. I have written a WDF driver and DLL that work. I am creating an application in C# to access the hardware through the DLL. There is a specific function that is causing an ExecutionEngineException soon after it is first called. Here is the function definition from the DLL:

```
DECLDIR int ReadDatagram(int channel, unsigned long *msgID, unsigned int *msgType, int *msgLen, unsigned int *data);
```

In my C# application code, I import this function with the following lines:

```
[DllImport("pcmcanDLL.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern int ReadDatagram(int channel, ref uint msgID, ref uint msgType, ref int msgLen, uint[] data);
```

When I start the application and open a channel, this function is periodically called by a timer. After a short indefinite time, I get the following exception message. If I comment out he call of this function, the application never has an issue.

Mesage: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

My application code is here. I believe I am handling the pointer arguments correctly because occasionally this will work a few times and the data is good in those ceases. Appreciate any insights.

```
private void rcvTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int channel = 1;
    String dsplyString = "Packet Received\n";
    uint msgID = 0, msgType = 0;
    int msgLen = 0;
    uint[] data = new uint[8];
    ErrorTypes dllReturn = ErrorTypes.RCV_BUFFER_EMPTY;

    do
    {
        dllReturn = (ErrorTypes)NativeMethods.ReadDatagram(channel, ref msgID, ref msgType, ref msgLen, data);

        if (dllReturn != ErrorTypes.SUCCESS && dllReturn != ErrorTypes.RCV_BUFFER_EMPTY)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error receiving packet.", "Receipt Error",
               MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            break;
        }
        else if (dllReturn == ErrorTypes.SUCCESS)
        {
           dsplyString = String.Format("{0}  {1}  {2}  {3}\n", channel, msgID, msgType, msgLen);
        }
    } while (dllReturn != ErrorTypes.RCV_BUFFER_EMPTY);

}
```

Comment: Have also seen the following error message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: It's pretty hard to say what you are doing wrong because there is no specification of how the DLL must be called. It's not enough just to know the types of parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Try following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

    }
    public enum ErrorTypes : int
    {
        RCV_BUFFER_EMPTY = 0,
        SUCCESS = 1
    }
    public class Test
    {
        [DllImport("pcmcanDLL.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern int ReadDatagram(int channel, ref uint msgID, IntPtr msgType, ref int msgLen, IntPtr dataPtr);

        private void rcvTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int channel = 1;
            String dsplyString = "Packet Received\n";
            uint msgID = 0;
            uint msgType = 0;
            int msgLen = 0;
            uint[] data = new uint[8];


            ErrorTypes dllReturn = ErrorTypes.RCV_BUFFER_EMPTY;

            IntPtr dataPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(data));
            IntPtr msgTypePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(msgType));
            do
            {
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(msgType, msgTypePtr, true);
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(data, dataPtr, true);
                dllReturn = (ErrorTypes)ReadDatagram(channel, ref msgID, msgTypePtr, ref msgLen, dataPtr);


                if (dllReturn != ErrorTypes.SUCCESS && dllReturn != ErrorTypes.RCV_BUFFER_EMPTY)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error receiving packet.", "Receipt Error",
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    break;
                }
                else if (dllReturn == ErrorTypes.SUCCESS)
                {
                   dsplyString = String.Format("{0}  {1}  {2}  {3}\n", channel, msgID, msgType, msgLen);
                }
            } while (dllReturn != ErrorTypes.RCV_BUFFER_EMPTY);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dataPtr);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(msgTypePtr);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many mistakes here

Comment: You didn't even try the code so how do you know it doesn't work?  All you ever do is make negative comments and never post a real solution.

Comment: Look at my record in the pinvoke tag and see that's not true.

Comment: The why didn't you post a solution here?

Comment: Because there isn't enough information to answer definitively. Your use of IntPtr is, again, odd. All of these types can be marshaled naturally by the pinvoke framework. There's no need to do it manually. And if you do it manually, which you don't need to, but if you do it should be done right. Which you didn't do. I don't want to explain why you got it wrong, because I did so in previous questions and you didnt listen.

Comment: No. There's really no way you could interpret my comments in that way. Do you want to know what's wrong, or are you 100% certain you are correct?